# Ftp-Storage Implementation in React-Native App

Tags: c#, react-native, asp.net-core, ftp, vps

I'm building an application in RN that has a C# backend.
In my application, which includes a blog, I need the logged-in user to be able to upload and download files, such as images or videos.
What is the best implementation? Because I can't find a package that is compatible with both Android and iOS.
I would greatly appreciate your response. Regards!

I have a VPS on Hostinger, which provides me with FTP access. However, FTP packages for RN are only compatible with Android apps. Perhaps I need some other guidance.

Comment: Can you try this abstraction API - https://www.ftp-api.com/

Comment: @Fiston _what_? A REST API that basically is a proxy to any FTP server whose URL and credentials you pass on the request? What...? Why...? Why would someone use something like that? How do you prevent your credentials from leaking to the client? Why would you trust such a site with your credentials?